# Android Push Notifications with Parse on Back4App not being received

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, back4app

I've configured Push notifications in Android for an app following all the instructions in:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-Server/wiki/Push-Configuring-Clients
https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/android/guide/#push-notifications

But no matter what I do, the mobile phone I'm using can't seem to get any push notifications at all.

The same app is configured to receive the notifications on iOS and works perfectly.

These are the relevant bits in the Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xxy.xxy">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<permission
    android:name="com.xxy.xxy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.xxy.xxy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


<application
    android:name="com.xxy.xxy.MiXXYApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logoapp"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

   <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.xxy.xxy" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
        android:value="id:123456789012" />
</application>
```

This is the Application class (with the AppID and Client Key replaced with the current value given by Back4App):

```
public class MiXXYApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);
        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .applicationId("back4App_AppID")
                .clientKey("back4App_ClientKey")
                .server("https://parseapi.back4app.com/")
                .build()
        );

    }
}
```

These are the methods I call to register the installation (I can't do it on the Application class because I need the userId, after login)

```
public void enablePush(final String userId) {
    ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
    installation.put("GCMSenderId", "123456789012");
    installation.put("userId", userId);
    installation.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.i("push", "ok");
                subscribe("");
                subscribe(userId);
            } else {
                Log.i("push", "nok");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


public void subscribe(String channel){
    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(channel, new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.i("Push", "subscribed");
            } else {
                Log.i("push", "nok");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is the installation registry on the Parse DB:

```
ObjectID: l1tkO3YM2r
GCMSenderID: 123456789012
deviceToken: APA91bHeKnj...
localeIdentifier: en-US
badge: (undefined)
parseVersion: 1.13.1
ACL: Public Read + Write
appIdentifier: com.xxy.xxy
appName: appName
deviceType: android
channels: ["","CyTPw5xc4r"]
pushType: gcm
installationId: 8cf9c606-5a0e...
userId: CyTPw5xc4r
```

In the google developer console, the project number is 123456789012, I've created an API key and added the API key + the project number in the Back4App dashboard's Android Push Notification Settings.

The logcat in verbose mode is showing the following:

```
09-21 09:29:19.863 10721-10721/com.xxy.xxy V/com.parse.ManifestInfo: Using gcm for push.
09-21 09:29:19.884 10721-10885/com.xxy.xxy V/com.parse.CachedCurrentInstallationController: Successfully deserialized Installation object
09-21 09:29:19.899 10721-10886/com.xxy.xxy V/com.parse.GcmRegistrar: Sending GCM registration intent
09-21 09:29:29.782 10721-11340/com.xxy.xxy V/com.parse.GcmRegistrar: Received deviceToken <APA91bHeKnj...> from GCM.
```

For what I can tell, everything's good to go, but I'm not getting any notification in my phone.

Is there anything wrong with my setup?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

The thing is that, instead of getting the Api key the way all the guides say, you should get it from https://developers.google.com/mobile/add.

It generated another API key and activated the service, and then, it worked.